# How to create CosmosDB User Defined Function programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template

I know how to create CosmosDB databases and collection using [ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/allversions). I have a UDF (User Defined Function) that I would like to deploy using an ARM template as well but it doesn't seem to be supported.

Am I missing something? Is there a different way to programmatically deploy/maintain a UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using Cosmos Db sdk or [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-user-defined-function) to deploy udf into your collection.

sample code:

```
string udfId = "Tax";
var udfTax = new UserDefinedFunction
{
    Id = udfId,
    Body = {...your udf function body},
};

Uri containerUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("myDatabase", "myContainer");
await client.CreateUserDefinedFunctionAsync(containerUri, udfTax);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer **`No`**, [Stored procedures and User Defined Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-sql-with-resource-manager) are not supported via Azure Resource Management Templates as of today.

Answer (score -1):

This is now possible..

```
"type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/userDefinedFunctions",         
"apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/2019-08-01/databaseaccounts/sqldatabases/containers/userdefinedfunctions